# ruby on rails: Duplicate many-to-many association table from existing table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I have two tables with data in it. Both of them have many-to-many association on a join table.

While there's a way to duplicate both tables and data but in different ids, but is there a way to also duplicate their may-to-many relationship given their existing relationship was joined via their existing unique id....

Answer (score 1):

You can use [gem amoeba](https://github.com/amoeba-rb/amoeba), which is used for cloning active record objects including associations

```
s = Supplier.create(supplier_name: "Supplier 1")
s.products.create(product_name: 'Product 1')
s.products.create(product_name: "Product 2")

puts Product.all.count # should be 2

my_copy = s.amoeba_dup
my_copy.save

puts Product.all.count # should be 4
```